# Cannot understand enums in a real world application

Tags: java, enums

I'm trying to understand when can I use the enums in Java.

So, let's say I have three enums values :

```
enum Activity {
    STUDENT, MECANICIAN, TEACHER
}
```

How can make use of this enum class in an existing `Person` class ? How is it persisted in a database?

```
class Person {
    private String name;
    private String age;
    private String activity; // !!!
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html

Comment: ok ... how is it persisted in a database (ex: mysql) ? can we retrieve thoses values from the database easily with other languages ?

Comment: You could persist the string representation of every enum constant.

Comment: How it's persisted in a database depends entirely on your particular application. There are many different ways Java objects can be persisted.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just add the enum to `Person`:

```
class Person {
    private String name;
    private String age;
    private Activity activity; 
}
```

One way to persist this field is to use an ORM such as [Hibernate](http://www.hibernate.org/), for example:

```
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private Activity activity;
```

would map the field to a text type field in the database.

Answer (score 0):

They help to take the place of having to use abstract integers. Instead of job=1 it's job=STUDENT. Sure you could use numbers but your code will be hard to understand. Plus you can use activity as a necessary type. So whenever you have a function changeJob(int val) you can make it changeJob(activity val) to force one of your enigma being passed.

Answer (score 0):

Enum is iterable, which is great, if you want to use the values like this:

```
public static String getStatusStr(Status s) {
    return Messages.get("softDeleteable.status." + s.name());
}

public static List<DropDownData> getStatusDataSource() {
    List<DropDownData> retval = new ArrayList<DropDownData>();

    for(Status s : Status.values()) {
        retval.add(new DropDownData(s.name(), getStatusStr(s) ));
    }

    return retval;
}
```

Where DropDownData is a simple value, label object, and Messages is for translating (Play framework)